# Is извините old-fashioned? Is there an alternative?

Tags: словоупотребление

Someone told me people don't actually use извините anymore. Is that true? Is there a more common alternative, nowadays?

Comment: It is interesting what whas "someone"'s recommendation to use instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Извини́те** is not at all archaic or old-fashioned, it is neutral and most typical. There are alternatives, **прости́те** and **прошу́ проще́ния**, they all are absolute synonyms, only the latter is just a bit more formal.

Comment: *прости́тие* should be *прости́те*.

Answer (score 1):

First, `извините` is used intensively nowadays.

Also you can hear in colloquial Russian `извиняюсь` but that is officially <s>incorrect</s> is not recommended although almost 90 people from 100 pronounce it instead of `извините`.

<s>`извиняюсь`</s> is technically possible, but grammatically means "I am being forgiven" so practically that's not a use case because nobody says "I forgive (myself)" to somebody when acts wrongly.

EDIT:
to prove this point I quote the explanation from two Russian Language forums:

- [from hashcode.ru](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/2798/%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%8C-%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)

Если Вы обращаетесь к тому, перед кем хотите извиниться, то это неправильно и с точки зрения этикета, и грамматически, ведь постфикс -СЯ образовался от возвратного местоимения "Себя" и его главное значение возвратное. Извиняюсь - извиняю себя (Ср.Умываюсь -умываю себя)

- [from gramota.ru](http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/trudnosti/36_89)

Вопрос
Как правильно: извини, извините или извиняюсь?

Форма извиняюсь - разговорно-просторечная. Вот как писал о слове извиняюсь известный русский лингвист А. Селищев: «Со времени войны (1914 г.) в России вошел в широкое употребление словеcный знак вежливости-извинения "извиняюсь" (извиняюс). По основе и по форме это образование употреблялось и раньше. "Опять тысячу раз извиняюсь, что сбиваюсь с прямой дороги в сторону" - писал Гончаров. "Извиняюсь, что не ответил никому до сих пор" - в "Дневнике писателя" Достоевского. Отличие от теперешнего извиняюсь заключалось в том, что извиняюсь в речи Гончарова, Достоевского и других находилось в сочетании с другими словами в предложении и имело обычное реальное значение, - значение выражения извинения, искреннего, иногда глубокого раскаяния, что подчеркивалось словами "1000 раз" и т. п. Посредством этой формы извиняется и взволнованный чеховский дядя Ваня. "Ну, ну, моя радость, простите... Извиняюсь (целует руку)". Совсем не по своему реальному и формальному значению теперешнее извиняюсь: оно употребляется отрывочно, вне сочетания с другими словами, служит формальным словесным знаком, произносимым при определенных обстоятельствах, - знаком, мало соответствующим этим обстоятельствам: полного значения просьбы здесь не выражается» (А. Селищев. Язык революционной эпохи. 1928). Написано давно, а актуально до сих пор.
В современных толковых словарях форма извиняюсь также дана с пометой разг. (разговорное).

*in modern dictionaries this word is given with the status **spoken***
Правильно извини, извините, слово извиняюсь полного значения просьбы не выражает. Извиняюсь – это как «товарищ коллежский асессор».

**Правильно**
**извини, извините.**

Correct:**извини, извините.**

So you can see that it's true that this word is old fashioned but nevertheless  this word is widely used nowadays.

Comment: @Shady_arc that's incorrect, check your sources before posting or downvote and see my added explanation to the _edit_ part.

Comment: Having thought about that for a few minutes — try to read your sources because what you said directly contradicts what they say. I have no problems with gramota.ru, and actually it is the first source I used  to check. The words is listed in dictionaries, just not recommended, especially if you aim for neutral speech. My dictionary of difficulties(1974) also specifically notes that "извиняться" is "not recommended as an expression for apology". Which is not quite the same as "officially incorrect" especially for a language learner (who should use neutral variants but know much more than that).

Comment: @Shady_arc accepted. putting this to _incorrect_ was too much, it's _is not recommended_ now.